# Keep variable value

Tags: android, service

My application has only one **service** class (not activity) in which I keep value of one variable that is being dynamically calculated through one method. Then i need to save that value for further comparing.
For example:

```
class MyClass extends Service{

static int number1;


private void Method(){
int number 2;

/// some calculations for number2 ///

if number2 != number1 { number1 = number2 }

}
```

I need to compare that variable (number1) to the some other variable (number2) that my application has calculated. This is working well, but when Android OS kills my service, and start that service on some intent (let say after phone reboot) the value of number1 is being lost and I can't use it for comparing. 
So how to do it? I thought to write simple TXT file in which one i could keep value of number1 after killing the service,

is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the quickest way is to save your variable's value in SharedPreferences and retrieve it for later use.

For example:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

this code is taken from [android developer's page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) which is for Activity but you may adapt it in your service easily by changing it

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the value to a file or a database as Android users usually monitor services and applications and can close the service
so 
persist it in database so later when your service is started you can check the saved value.

Comment: Thank you bo2bo2 for answer, i've used SharedPreferences, it's easier!